# Выбор элементов и изменение их ширины

Tags: jquery

Как при помощи jQuery выбрать все элементы, у которых задана ширина в CSS, и изменить их ширину?

Comment: Только если ширину задавать с помощью какого-нибудь конкретного класса, иначе никак, т.к. шириной обладают все элементы на странице.

Буду очень удивлён, если кто-то меня опровергнет.

Comment: Вся беда в том что все стили (речь идет о width) написаны пикселами подогнаны под разрешение 1280х1024 и при 1024 на 780 видно лишь где то 60 процентов странички а менять неохота и слишком долго придется возиться не знаете как быстренько поправить?

Answer (score 2):

1. копаем в сторону `document.styleSheets[].cssRules[].style[]` получаем списки стилей парсим, получаем теги и вот тут с помощью jQuery задаем новую ширину.
2. подгружаем аяксом файлы стилей и парсим их. в этом случае скрипты прописанные в html не будут учтены, да и хлопотно.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. jQuery работает напрямую с элементами страницы, но в CSS-файл не заглядывает. Поэтому, даже если в CSS для элемента не задан никакой параметр, то всё равно jQuery будет определять его ширину: пусть нулевую, но вычислит.